# Determine the rational numbers $a\geq 2$ such that if $m, n\in \mathbb{N^*}$ and $(an + m)\mid (am + n)$, then $n\mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the rational numbers $a\geq 2$ for which the implication occurs. If $m, n\in \mathbb{N^*}$ and $(an + m)\mid (am + n)$ then $n\mid m$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What does $(an + m)\mid (am + n)$ even mean if $an+m$ or $am+n$ is not an integer?

Comment: @TonyK it means that if $an+m$  and $am+n$ are integers and divide each other form some $n,m$  then $n$ must divide $m$

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak: Perhaps you are right. I hope Adele can edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  As you can see from the comments, it is not clear what $(an+m)\,|\,(am+n)$ means for rational $a$.  Did you mean to say that $a$ was an integer?  Alternatively, did you mean to say that the desired implication should only hold for those $n,m$ such that $a\times n$ and $a\times m$ are integers?  Something else?

Comment: I don't know for sure what does it mean but I believe that it means that $\frac{am+n}{an+m}$ has to be an integer

Comment: I agree with Adele that it's the generalized divisibility notation that $ a \mid b $ means $ a = kb$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Now do you have any ideas ?

Comment: $(an+m)|(am + n)$ means there is an integer $k$ so that $(am+n)=k(an+m)$.  There is utterly no requirement that $am+n$ or $an+m$ be integers or even rational.  $\sqrt{3}|\sqrt{12}$ becase $\sqrt{12}=2\times \sqrt 3$.  And $\frac {\pi}2|3\pi$ because $3\pi = 6\times \frac{\pi}2$ but $\pi\not\mid \pi^2$ because $k \frac{\pi^2}{\pi}=\pi$ is not an integer.  Also $\frac 59| 3\frac 13$ as $6\times \frac 59= 3\frac 13$ is a perfectly legitimate statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is wrong / incomplete.**
Major issue: Assumed that $a$ is an integer to justify $an+m \mid (a^2-1) n$.
Minor(?) issue: With odd integers $a$ (Case 2c).

---

(This first part is purely to motivate how I came up with the solution. You can skip it.)
Let's play with the case $ a = 2$.
If $ 2n+m \mid 2m + n$, so $2n + m \leq 2m + n \Rightarrow n \leq m$.
We also have $ 2n + m \mid 2m+n - 2(m+2n) = - 3n$  so $ 2n + m \leq 3n \Rightarrow m \leq n$.
Thus, $m = n$, and $n\mid m$.
So $ a = 2$ is a solution.

Note: It should be a slight surprise that we can force $m = n$.

Let's play with the case $ a = 3$.
We have $ 3n + m \mid 3(m+3n) - (3m+n) = 8n$.
Since $ \frac{8n}{3} < 3n$, hence any factor of $8n$ that is larger than $3n$ is either $\frac{8n}{2} = 4n$ or $\frac{8n}{1} = 8n$. In either case, we have $m = n, m = 5n$ so $ n \mid m$.
So $a = 5$ is a solution.

Let's play with the case $ a = 5$.
Likewise we have $ 5n + m \mid 24n$.
Since $\frac{24n}{1} = 24n$, $\frac{24n}{2} = 12n$, $\frac{24n}{3} = 8n$, $\frac{24n}{4} = 6n$, $\frac{24n}{5} = 4 \frac{4}{5}n$, hence any factor of $24n$ that is larger than $5n$ is also a multiple of $n$.
So $a = 5$ is a solution.

---

Now let's see how we can generalize it.
If $an + m \mid am + n$ then $ n \leq m$.
Also $an+m \mid am + n \Leftrightarrow an+m \mid a(an+m) - (am+n) = (a^2-1) n$.
Observe that $\frac{ (a^2-1)n } { an + m } < \frac{ (a^2-1)n } { an } = a - \frac{1}{a}$.

**Case 1:** $ a - \frac{1}{a} \leq 2$, which means $ a \leq 1 + \sqrt{2}$.
$an + m \mid (a^2 -1) n \Rightarrow  1 \times an+m = (a^2 -1)n$, or that $(a^2 - a - 1) n = m$.
If $ a^2 - a - 1 = 1$, then we have $ a = 2$ (This is our case above, $n=m$.)
If $ a^2 - a - 1 = 2$, then we have $ a = \frac{ 1 + \sqrt{13}}{2}$, which is not rational.
If $ a^2 - a - 1 = 3$, then $ a > 1 + \sqrt{2}$, which is out of range.

**Case 2:** $ a - \frac{1}{a} > 2$
Given that we cannot force uniqueness, this opens up more options for us. After playing around, it seems like we can always find counter examples, so let's see how we create one generally.
The goal is to select integers $(n,m)$ such that $ \frac{ (a^2 - 1)n}{(an+m)} = 2$, and hope that $ n \not \mid m$.
If $ a = \frac{p}{q}$ with $ \gcd (p,q) = 1$, then the equation is $(p^2  -2pq - q^2) n  = 2q^2m$.

Case 2a, $ q \neq 1$: Checking the obvious solution $n = 2q^2, m = p^2 - 2pq - q^2$, we have $q\mid n$ and $q \not \mid m$, so $ n \not \mid m$.
Case 2b, $ q = 1$ and $a$ is even: set $n =2 , m = a^2 - 2a - 1$.
Case 2c, $ q=1$ and $p$ is odd: Let $r$ be the smallest prime that doesn't divide $a^2 -1 $.
Set $n = r$, $m =  (a^2 -1)  - ar$, seems to work. However, the issue here is we require $(a^2 -1)  - ar > 0$, which isn't true for $ a =3 $ (and possibly others) SIGH.

This is our desired counter example.

---

Note: The condition that $a$ is rational allows us to find the counter example in Case 2. Otherwise, that part seems mostly hopeless. However, given the interesting result in Case 1, a better way to present this question is:

> Determine all real numbers $ a \in [ 2, 1 + \sqrt{2} ]$ such that if $ \frac{ ax + 1 }{a+x} \in \mathbb{N}^+$, then $ x \in \mathbb{N}^+$.